# How can i replace a table string with another table string?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a little problem with my mysql that I can't solve myself.

My problem is very simple: I want to update `locale_name` in `item_proto` table, when

```
item_proto_copy.name = item_proto.vnum!
```

Comment: So basically you want to [update with a join](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+update+with+join), this question is pretty much a duplicated and without example and or expected results we also can't help you see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ["13.2.12 UPDATE Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: i only hope the topicstarter will not use the old ansi comma join syntax mentioned in the manual link you have provided @stickybit